# Pulldown resistor between ICs?

Tags: cmos, pulldown

I'm building a 24hr clock out of discrete logic, and I forgot to include pulldown resistors, so I'm going back and adding them.  [image: Here's the schematic for reference.]  I know to put pulldown resistors on the switch inputs, but do I also put them in between the ICs, such as the line between the CD40192BE and CD4543BE?  I've been using 10KΩ resistors because I've heard those are good values, but if they aren't, what should I use?

Comment: Perhaps read [here](https://wiki.analog.com/_media/university/courses/4000_series_article.pdf) and pay attention to Figure 3 and surrounding text. (Assuming your devices fit. Given the numbering, I suspect they do. But I've not compared their datasheets.)

Comment: Why are pull-down resistors needed?

Comment: @SimonFitch to avoid floating inputs

Comment: @periblepsis it says that I can short-circuit output pins at 5V with no problem, so does that mean I should go ahead and put in the resistors?

Comment: Can you give me an example of where you would place such a resistor, at which floating input? I'm having a hard time locating one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an input is driven from another IC, and the driver has an output that stays driven either high or low all the time, and doesn't ever go high impedance, like some enableable buffer or switch ICs sometimes can, then there's no need for a further component to pull it high or low.

It should be possible to use a component as high as 10k without causing a problem as a pulldown, but why?

You might want to for other reasons. For debugging purposes, you might build your design as several sections, and separate them for test. Put pulldowns on any inputs that become floating as a result of splitting the circuit. You might want test points for checking or inserting signals, a big 1206 footprint of a large value or not used resistor would be a convenient way to create one.